# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import a function from a module using Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

I have two python files in the same directory, with untitled.ipynb being the main script and Data_extractor.ipynb being the module I want to extract multiple functions from.
[image: Directory]

So I tried to extract the function called BOM_data_extractor from module Data_extractor, but got the ModuleNotFoundError.
I then ran import sys and printed the default paths and one of the paths was the same directory that contained both the files.
[image: Results]

Is there a way to do this correctly? I probably am doing something wrong

Following @Arne recommendation of changing the Data_extractor to .py, I just changed the extension name and then ran it again. I got the following error, which is strange seeing that I do not have these lines in my code.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-7459b354f559> in <module>
     17 if module_path not in sys.path:
     18     sys.path.append(module_path)
---> 19 from Data_extractor import BOM_data_extractor

~\Desktop\Sem 4\ENGN8601\PythonCode\Data_extractor.py in <module>
    123   {
    124    "cell_type": "code",
--> 125    "execution_count": null,
    126    "metadata": {},
    127    "outputs": [],

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Comment: have you tried changing `Data_extractor.ipynb` into `Data_extractor.py`? I don't know if jupiter does some magic to allow importing from `ipynb` files as well, but by default, imports only work from proper `py` files.

Comment: Meaning you not only have to change the name, the file itself also needs to be in the `py` file format.

Comment: I did that.. changed the extension to .py, but got this following error then ( had to re-edit the question to show the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so @Arne's comment of changing the filetype to .py instead of ipynb worked,.. I initially tried to just manually change the file extension, but that resulted in some null errors.
Then I realised I had to go through Jupyter>File>Download as> Python file(.py)
once this .py file was downloaded, I was able to call it without any issue.

Comment: glad you could sort this out!